# android treating a sound without recording or encoding it

Tags: java, android, audio, capture

I want to create a android application using voice recognition, without reusing existing apps.

I need to capture a sound to analize it next, and for that I've seen I could use MediaRZecorder [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html), but that way it seems I'm oblige to record and encode it before being able to analyze it, while I'd just want to treat it immediatly.

How can I do that?